# Is there a function that can write suspend function like Future&then in Dart?

Tags: kotlin, dart

sample code in dart:

```
void main() {
  step1().then(step2).then(step3).then(print);
}

Future<String> step1() async {
  return Future.value("setp1");
}

Future<int> step2(String input) async {
  return Future.value(input.length);
}

Future<bool> step3(int input) async {
  return Future.value(input > 3);
}
```

is there any way to write code in kotlin like this?

I use flow to write a simple code, but I won't find a way to simplify it

```
suspend fun step1(): String {
    return "step1"
}

suspend fun step2(input: String): Int {
    return input.length
}

suspend fun step3(input: Int): Boolean {
    return input > 3
}

suspend fun execute() {
    flowOf(step1())
        .map { step2(it) }
        .map { step3(it) }
        .collect { print(it) }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're saying you just want to run the suspend functions sequentially. If so, it doesn't look any different than non-suspending code.

```
suspend fun execute(){
  val result1 = step1()
  val result2 = step2(result1)
  print(step3(result2))
}
```

If you really want to chain functions that are not extension functions, you can use `run` or `let`, although some might say this is less readable

```
suspend fun execute() = step1()
  .run(::step2)
  .run(::step3)
  .run(::print)
```

If your functions are defined as extensions:

```
suspend fun String.step2() = length
suspend fun Int.step3() = this > 3
```

then you can chain directly:

```
suspend fun execute() = step1()
  .step2()
  .step3()
  .run(::print)
```

Answer (score 1):

kotlin coroutine does not adopt Promise like APIs (then/map/flatMap) because with suspend function, this can be done much easier

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.yield

suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val one = step1()
    val two = step2(one)
    val three = step3(two)
    println(three)
}

suspend fun <T> resolve(value: T): T {
    yield() // to simulate Future.resolve
    return value
}

suspend fun step1() = resolve("100")
suspend fun step2(input: String) = resolve(input.length)
suspend fun step3(input: Int) = resolve(input > 3)
```

see discussions below

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/342

Answer (score 0):

**Using Coroutines in Kotlin**

Synchronous run with three functions: here we perform three tasks in a coroutine and return the three results of the tasks in a Triple class.

```
suspend fun workWithThreeTimes(time1: Int, time2: Int, time3: Int): Triple<Result, Result, Result> {
    return coroutineScope {
        val result1 = manager.workForTime(time1) // work1
        val result2 = manager.workForTime(time2) // work2 after work1
        val result3 = manager.workForTime(time3) // work3 after work2
        Triple(result1, result2, result3)
    }
}
```

Parallel run with three functions: here we perform three works, in parallel, in a coroutine and return the three results of the tasks in a Triple class.

```
suspend fun workWithThreeTimesParallel(time1: Int, time2: Int, time3: Int): Triple<Result, Result, Result> {
    return coroutineScope {
        val work1 = async { manager.workForTime(time1) } // Async work1
        val work2 = async { manager.workForTime(time2) } // Async work2 while work1 is working
        val result3 = manager.workForTime(time3) // work3 while work1 and work2 are working
        val result1 = work1.await() // non-blocking wait
        val result2 = work2.await()// non-blocking wait
        Triple(result1, result2, result3)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this answer, but i want a code that i don't need to get a function's result and then pass to next function, because there may have many function to run